# Cost function with Nan values in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I'm implementing a neural network to map one vector of 194 values to another vector of 5 values. Values are float numbers from an interval of `-10, 10` on.

The problem with my code below is that the `avg_cost` printed in the end is always `Nan`. I've read somewhere that it happened because the guy didn't set the activation function of the output layer correctly, but I've set mine as it is (linear activation which is the default one). I'm a newbie in this area and to Tensorflow and so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is the linear activation function a correct decision? Or is something else wrong in my code?

```
def neural_net(x):
    layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=97, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=5)
    return out_layer

train_x = pd.read_csv("x_data.csv", sep=" ")
train_y = pd.read_csv("y_data.csv", sep=" ")

train_size = 0.9

train_cnt = int(floor(train_x.shape[0] * train_size))
x_train = train_x.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
y_train = train_y.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
x_test = train_x.iloc[train_cnt:].values
y_test = train_y.iloc[train_cnt:].values

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 194])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 5])


nn_output = neural_net(x)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=nn_output))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(cost)


training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 30

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        total_batch = int(len(x_train) / batch_size)
        x_batches = np.array_split(x_train, total_batch)
        y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], 
                            feed_dict={
                                x: batch_x, 
                                y: batch_y, 
                                keep_prob: 0.8
                            })
            avg_cost += c / total_batch

        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no nans in the input data?

Comment: Actually I had them there, so I thought it's because of them. But then a removed them and now there are just real numbers. And the cost is still nan.

Comment: The cost can be NaN if some of your model parameters are NaN, which can happen if some intermediate values have floating point over / under flow.

Comment: And what can be done about that? I cannot influence how the FP arithmetic is done, can I? The float numbers in my input file have max. 9 digits after the decimal mark (-x.xxxxxxxxx), could it be that it is too many?

Comment: Ok, I found what's wrong. There was one more white character in the end of each row of the csv file. The read function probably made Nan values from it somehow.